# Remeshing self overlapping mesh?

Tags: modeling, remesh

So here's the object I am trying to remesh :

[image]

and, in sculpt mode, I am trying to smooth the edges where the rings are intersecting. (circled in red)

But heres a picture of how mesh looks like :

[image]

So I created this object by boolean union.

and as you can see the circled red area are inside the top ring, and does not intersect with the top ring surface where they meet.

In order to smooth out the intersection, I have to have vertex intersections.

How can I do this?

Things I have tried :

1. Remesh modifier & voxel remesh
   [image]

It makes my final mesh too angulated, and cant figure out how to avoid this.

2. Quadriflow Remesh

Doesnt seem to remove the overlapping area.

Comment: hello, do you mean that the intersections are too angulated? Also, you don't show the wireframe so it's hard to guess what you could do, probably dissolve some edges, but maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello, huge huge thanks always, by angulated I meant that when I decrease voxel size to increase remesh quality, it ends up angulating the mesh like the last image in this post. eg the voxel size for the mesh in that image was 0.01. 

+ I just uploaded my file, I included both before & after boolean versions of the mesh within the file. big thanks again!

Comment: you need to share the link it gives you  ;)

Comment: my bad, https://pasteall.org/blend/17ad48db43ed487cbde3ab362c24c8de

Comment: if your goal is to boolean the 2 shapes, it seems to work fine, you'll just need to rework the intersections a bit. If your mesh was lower in polygons it would make the things easier (and give it a Subdivision Surface modifier to round the shape)

Comment: see the kind of topology you could get: https://zupimages.net/up/21/31/ipxz.jpg

Comment: actually you should work with a simpler topology, only work on one segment, mirror it on the Z axis and make it rotate 72° to repeat all around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with less polygons. As you'll have 5 torus, maybe create a 40 *Major Segments*/10 *Minor Segments* torus at the beginning so that you'll easily rotate them 72° later. Rotate it vertically, cut vertically to keep a half, duplicate it 5 times and rotate 72° on Z. Booleans them, rework the topology a bit on 1 of the middle intersections and 1 of the top intersections to get this kind of result:

[image]

Then, delete 4/5 of the object and duplicate/rotate again, and at last merge by distance.

Comment: by rework topology did you mean merging vertices one by one?

Comment: yes, dissolve, merge, join, etc... You need to do it manually, that's why it would be better to have a low poly mesh

Comment: didnt know retopoloy was another field that needs studying, thanks for the help!